# Product of central binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have a question about an equality involving products of central binomial coefficients. If $x_1,...,x_n$ and $y_1,...,y_n$ are positive integers, with $\sum_i x_i = \sum_i y_i$ and 
$$ \binom{2x_1}{x_1} \cdots \binom{2x_n}{x_n} = \binom{2y_1}{y_1}\cdots \binom{2y_n}{y_n}\,, $$
what are the restrictions on the $x_i$ and $y_i$, and is there any solution other than the trivial one $\{x_1,...,x_n\}=\{y_1,...,y_n\}$?

Comment: You might consider counting powers of 2 appearing in both sides, as well as powers of large primes appearing in the products. I would expect that a proof (for existence of an interesting solution) of n > 2 to be feasible, and that n> 4 is more likely.

Comment: Primes that appear in central binomial coefficients are relatively small, so if you assemble the multiplicities of primes in vectors, there will be many linear dependencies, and you will obtain identities like $\binom{8}{4}^3\binom{4}{2}^8\binom{14}{7}^2=\binom{16}{8}^2\binom{6}{3}\binom{2}{1}^7\binom{10}{5}^3$. However, the sum of $x_i$ on one side there is $42$, and on the other side is $41$. I have no good intuition whether one should expect the exact equality of sums or not.

Comment: If you go up to 22-choose-11, you get three more binomial coefficients, and only two more primes. I suspect that gives enough wiggle room to make $\sum x_i=\sum y_i$.

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there are nontrivial solutions.  The first I found, with $n=5$, has
$$
\lbrace x_i \rbrace = \lbrace 2, 5, 8, 13, 19 \rbrace,
\phantom{\infty}
\lbrace y_i \rbrace = \lbrace 3, 4, 6, 14, 20 \rbrace,
$$
with $\sum_i x_i = \sum_i y_i = 47$ and
$$
\prod_{i=1}^5 {2x_i \choose x_i} = \prod_{i=1}^5 {2y_i \choose y_i}
 = 7153522697506948963200000
 = 2^{10} 3^6 5^5 7^3 11^2 13^1 17^1 19^1 23^2 29^1 31^1 37^1.
$$
This is a "list anagram" problem in multiplicative disguise; 
for another such example see puzzle #12
[here](http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/index.html#puzzles)
and the notes and links in the
[solution](http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/sol12.html) page.

[**EDIT**] I see that the OP did not specify that the $x_i$ and $y_i$
be distinct, which makes it a simpler problem (only linear algebra
over the rationals, no lattice reduction).  But the version with
distinct variables is more appealing.

---

*[added later]* to spell it out: let $C(m) := {2m \choose m}$,
and suppose all $x_i,y_i$ are at most $M$.
For $1 \leq m \leq M$ let $a_m = \#\{i: x_i=m\} - \#\{i: y_i=m\}$.
Then $x_i,y_i$ are a solution **iff**
$\sum_{m=1}^M a_m = \sum_{m=1}^M m a_m = 0$ and $\prod_{m=1}^M C(m)^{a_m}=1$.
By unique factorization, the last condition is equivalent to
$\sum_{m=1}^M v_p(C(m)) a_m = 0$ for all primes $p$
(where $v_p$ is the $p$-valuation), and we need only consider $p \leq 2M$.
So we have $\pi(2M)+2$ linear equations in $M$ variables.
There are nontrivial solutions provided $\pi(2M)+2 < M$,
which happens once $M$ is large enough because $\pi(x) = o(x)$;
it turns out that any $M>10$ is large enough.
The equations have integer coefficients, so any solution is rational,
and can be made integral by multiplying by a common denominator.
For example, the 1-dimensional space of solutions for $M=11$
is generated by $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{11}) = (1,-2,0,0,2,-1,0,0,0,1,-1)$,
giving $n=4$, $x_i=1,5,5,10$, and $y_i=2,2,6,11$ with a common sum of $21$
and
$$
\prod_i C(x_i) = \prod_i C(y_i) = 23465490048 = 2^7 3^4 7^2 11^1 13^1 17^1 19^1.
$$
The $x_i$ and $y_i$ are distinct **iff** the $a_m$ are all $0$ or $\pm 1$.
There's no easy criterion for this, but it's correlated with small norm
$\sum_{m=1}^M |a_m|^2$, so we'll often find an example by applying LLL
(or some other technique for lattice basis reduction)
to the lattice of integer solutions of our linear system equation.
Fortunately the **matkerint** function of **gp** does this automatically,
and then **vecmax(abs(...))** can be used to detect vectors with all
coordinates $0$ or $\pm 1$.  A bit more work finds such a vector
already for $M=18$, with $n=6$ and
$x_i,y_i = \lbrace 3, 6, 8, 11, 13, 17\rbrace,
\lbrace 4, 5, 7, 10, 14, 18 \rbrace$.

Comment: ...and yes, ${20 \choose 5} = 15504$ and ${18 \choose 6} = 18564$
are small enough that these solutions could also have been found routinely
by listing all 5- or 6-element sets, sorting by 
$(\sum_i x_i, \prod_i C(x_i))$, and scanning for consecutive duplications.